# i have json array, how to compare elements of an array and to deduce those which do not coincide between with both, bash

Tags: arrays, json, bash, api

1. Hi everyone, i have an array of data that i get from API query, it looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo8JP.jpg)

> ```
> {
>   "employee": {
>     "id": 000001
>   },
>   "reviewed_by": {
>     "id": 000002
>   },
>   "reason": null,
>   "type": "Holiday",
>   "deducted": "3.0",
>   "cancelled": false,
>   "id": 11111111,
>   "start_date": "2021-02-11",
>   "half_start": false,
>   "half_start_am_pm": null,
>   "end_date": "2021-02-15",
>   "half_end": false,
>   "half_end_am_pm": null,
>   "action": "request",
>   "status": "approved",
>   "notes": "",
>   "created_at": "2021-01-25T14:36:06+00:00",
>   "updated_at": "2021-01-25T22:04:41+00:00"
> },
> ```

I am writing a condition in a bash script in order to percent this array of data, but I can't do it in one array, and I have to create this array to compare two arrays, and if the condition is fulfilled then show what is written in the condition,

as you can see in the picture my main array consists of smaller ones, I take one array and compare it with another, according to the following parameters (employee.id start_date end_date status action) and if the first 4 parameters coincide, and 5 differ from each other, then I deduce that coincided (actually I need to deduce that does not coincide).

```
> > set -f; IFS=$'\n'  arr=($BREATHE_HR_REQUESTS)   for row1 in ${arr[@]}; do 
>     employee_id1=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .employee.id`
>     start_date1=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .start_date`
>     end_date1=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .end_date` 
>     action1=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .action`
>     status1=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .status` 
>     holliday_id=`echo "${row1}" | jq .id`
>     breathe_hr_type=`echo "${row1}" | jq -r .type`
>     #except_ids1+=("$holliday_id")
>     for row2 in ${arr[@]}; do
>       employee_id2=`echo ${row2} | jq -r '.employee.id'`
>       start_date2=`echo ${row2} | jq -r .start_date`
>       end_date2=`echo ${row2} | jq -r .end_date` 
>       action2=`echo ${row2} | jq -r .action`
>       status2=`echo ${row2} | jq -r .status` 
>       for row3 in ${arr[@]}; do      
>         if [[ "$employee_id1" == "$employee_id2" ]]; then
>           if [[ "$start_date1" == "$start_date2" ]] && [[ "$end_date1" == "$end_date2" ]] && [[ "$status1" == "$status2" ]] && [[ "$action1" != "$action2" ]]; then
>             breathe_hr_check=`echo $row1`
>             holliday_id_cancel=`echo ${row1} | jq -r .id`
>             #echo $row1 | jq .id
>             #except_ids+=("$holliday_id_cancel")
>             echo ${arr[@]} | jq -c . 
>             #echo $id | jq .
>           fi
>         fi
>         break
>       done
>     done
```

question! how do I sort and retrieve items with one array and without three loops? on the bash

Comment: So your picture shows ".leave_requests" is an array of 3 objects. What output are you trying to achieve? Why are you comparing the objects? I'm quite sure bash is the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @glennjackman
thank you, you are right, I am closing this question